# How can I loop through this function for 30 ID's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I basically have to run this 30 times. The ID's follow on each other, each one having a new number.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
if($("#waybillvalue1").text().trim() == ''){
       $("#1stImageCont1").css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
         $("#1stImageCont1").on("click", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
         });
        }
});

</script>
```

So basically it must be for each "waybillvalue1 - waybillvalue30" it must perform the code below:

```
$("#1stImageCont1").css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
         $("#1stImageCont1").on("click", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
         });
        }
});
```

I don't know where to add the "for" and "i + 1" etc.

Here's what it needs to do:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var waybillslist=list.length;


for (var counter = 0; counter < waybillslist; counter++) {
if($("#waybillvalue"+counter).text().trim() == ''){

var listSize=list.length;
for (var counter = 0; counter < listSize; counter++) { 
    $("#1stImageCont"+counter).css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
             $("#1stImageCont"+counter).on("click", function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
             });
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: For all the loop iterations, do you want to perform the actions on `#1stImageCont1`?

Comment: Instead of using 30 individual IDs, use one class. `$(".someclass")` will select your 30 elements that have `class="someclass"`.

Comment: Use **attribute starts with** selector.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[id^="1stImageCont"]')

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention I the "1stImageCont1" also goed up to 30! Sorry

Comment: @31piy it must perform the actions on "#waybillvalue1"

Answer (score 2):

Just use this block code to do what you want

```
$("[id^='1stImageCont']").css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
         $("[id^='1stImageCont']").on("click", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
         });
        }
});
```

Read this [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) too.

Comment: It needs to do something like this: <script> $(document).ready(function () { var waybillslist=list.length; for (var counter = 0; counter < waybillslist; counter++) { if($("#waybillvalue"+counter).text().trim() == ''){ var listSize=list.length; for (var counter = 0; counter < listSize; counter++) { $("#1stImageCont"+counter).css('cursor', 'not-allowed'); $("#1stImageCont"+counter).on("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }); } }); } }); </script>

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just as simple as concatenate the counter in the id like:

```
var listSize=list.length;
for (var counter = 0; counter < listSize; counter++) { 
    $("#1stImageCont"+counter).css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
             $("#1stImageCont"+counter).on("click", function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
             });
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: It needs to do something like this: 

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var waybillslist=list.length;


for (var counter = 0; counter < waybillslist; counter++) {
if($("#waybillvalue"+counter).text().trim() == ''){

var listSize=list.length;
for (var counter = 0; counter < listSize; counter++) { 
    $("#1stImageCont"+counter).css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
             $("#1stImageCont"+counter).on("click", function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
             });
            }
  });
 }
});
</script>

Comment: Use `code` like this:
`<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
  var waybillslist=list.length; 
  for (var counter = 0; counter < waybillslist; 
  counter++) { if($("#waybillvalue"+counter).text().trim() == ''){ var listSize=list.length; for (var counter = 0; counter < listSize; counter++) { $("#1stImageCont"+counter).css('cursor', 'not-allowed'); $("#1stImageCont"+counter).on("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }); } }); } }); </script>`

Otherwise is impossible to read @MailBlade

Edit: Well, in a comment is just... that's it. Please add an answer :)

Comment: i only give reply to show how I did it, but it's not working